# Append values to div as array - jquery

Tags: jquery

i have a menu. These menu includes some artists and when admin clicks checkboxes, the artists is inserted to DB.

first of all,

```
function AddDataImdb(par, par2, par3) {

    var artistIds = [];
    $("input[name='" + par + "']:checked").each(function () {
        artistIds.push($(this).val());
    });

    $.post('/json/management/AddDataImdbAjax', {
        "artistIds": artistIds
    }, function (response) {
        if (response == 'error') {

            alert("Sanatçı bulunamadı, yönlendiriliyorsunuz");
            window.location.replace("myurl");

        } else {
            alert("succesfully added");
            $("#" + par2 + "").append(('<br /><input type="checkbox" name =' + par + ' value=' + response + ' />' + par3 + '<br />'));
        }
    });

}
```

With above code, i can add my div the new added artists.

The problem is that when admin insert 2 or more artist, it shows the last one as added

```
$("#"+par2+"").append(('<br /><input type="checkbox" name ='+par+' value='+response+' />'+par3+'<br />'));
```

Above code add the div. How can i  add these as array ? What can i do ?

Comment: what is your `response`?  it is not showing the last div, I think it appends only one div. To add multiple div you should loop over your `response`

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're wanting to occur. Do you want a new checkbox created if there are multiple values that come back in the response? How is `response` formatted?

Answer (score 1):

can you state more? what is the content of the response?

if your response is a list then you may do this:

```
$.each(reponse, function () {
    //append as div
}):
```

Comment: var myArr = response; i took my json like that can i use this like foreach in php ?

Comment: try using $.each(reponse, function (index, value) { });
OR 
$.map(response, function (value, key) {  });